# How to prevent navigating in Angular 2 without guards

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I injected the Router class , subscribed to its events property,
I was called when the navigating event occured, but now , how can I cancel the navigation?
Using navigation guards is overkill to my porpuse. Is there another way?

Comment: Why do you think guards are overkill? I think they're quite simple.

Comment: Overkill is not the right phrase but I have tons of routes and I need one simple check before continue routing, so I don't want to add guarde for each route

Answer (score 1):

I have read the angular repository with the same purpose, try to find a better way to cancel the navigation and got two solutions:

- The navigation guards;
- Override the navigation calls;

I personally like the guards, you could just provide one service that take care of the permissions for all components, just configuring it in the route config.
The second approach is not recommended but possible, to override the navigation calls, because the angular team closed the flow of the router, making it more difficult to modify, but created a great flow.